# loop through a json object and count elements with the same value in different arrays

Tags: arrays, json, count, for-in-loop

I want to loop through a json object and count elements with the same value in different arrays. Here's a sample of my object

```
var testconn =
{"_total": 3,
    "values":
    [
        {
            "articlesRead": [
                { "articleId": 1001 },
                { "articleId": 1002 },
                { "articleId": 1003 },
                { "articleId": 1004 },
                { "articleId": 1005 },
                { "articleId": 1006 }
            ]
        },
        {
            "articlesRead": [
                { "articleId": 1001 },
                { "articleId": 1002 },
                { "articleId": 2001 },
                { "articleId": 2002 },
                { "articleId": 2003 },
                { "articleId": 2004 }
            ]
        },
        {
            "articlesRead": [
                { "articleId": 1001 },
                { "articleId": 3001 },
                { "articleId": 3002 },
                { "articleId": 3003 },
                { "articleId": 3004 },
                { "articleId": 3005 }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to count how many the ID's exsist in the array. So for this example I shoud have:
1001 x 3
1002 x 2
1003 x 1
1004 x 1
2001 x 1 
etc

I'm looping through my object like this

```
for (i = 0; i < testconn.values.length; i++) {
    var c = testconn.values[i];
    for (j = 0; j < c.articlesRead.length; j++) {
        var a = c.articlesRead[j];
        for (var key in a) {
            if (a[key] is bigger then 1) {
                count a[key]
            }
            return number of

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an object to store the value as a key and increment it:

```
var id={};
for (var i = 0; i < testconn._total; i++) {
    var c = testconn.values[i];
    for (j = 0; j < c.articlesRead.length; j++) {
        var a = c.articlesRead[j];
        id[a.articleId]= id[a.articleId] ? ++id[a.articleId]: 1;
    }
}
console.log(id);
```

Comment: Excellent, this is what I was looking for (Is it to much to ask to note the if statement in its regular form? I'm not as advanced and would like to understand what you did)

Comment: I am using a ternary operator, it makes things shorter, it's the same as:if(id[a.articleId]) { ...} else {...}

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to go about it, using 4 nested for loops, maybe not the most efficient though.

```
var list = testconn.values;
var dict = {};  


for(var i in list){
    for(var j in list[i]){
        for(var k in list[i][j]){
            for(var l in list[i][j][k]){
                var key = list[i][j][k][l];
                dict[key] = dict[key] ? ++dict[key] : 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Dict is Now an associative array of what you want.